# How to generate bootstrap rows using a for loop

Tags: java, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, rows

I am currently trying to generate a contact page using this layout:
[image: My goal]

I am trying to do this by using a scriplet to get data from database then using a for loop to display it all in the layout I have.

This is the code I currently have:

```
     <% EmployeeDAO personalInfo = new EmployeeDAO();%>
        <% for (int i = 0; i < personalInfo.getTempPersonalInfo().size(); i++) {%>
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="clearfix"></div>                     



                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <h4 class="brief"><i>Digital Strategist</i></h4>
                                        <div class="left col-xs-7">
                                            <h2 id="applicantName<%=+i%>" id="applicantName<%=+i%>"><%=personalInfo.getTempPersonalInfo().get(i).getFirstName() + " "%><%=personalInfo.getTempPersonalInfo().get(i).getLastName()%></h2>
                                            <p><strong>About: </strong> Web Designer / UX / Graphic Artist / Coffee Lover </p>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Address: </li>
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone #: </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
                                            <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                                            <p class="ratings">
                                                <a>4.0</a>
                                                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                                                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                                                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                                                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></a>
                                                <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span></a>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                                            <button type="button" class="btnSelect btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#ViewProfileNew<%=+i%>"> <i class="fa fa-user">
                                                </i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> View Summary</button>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">
                                            <a href="viewApplicantProfile?id=<%=personalInfo.getTempPersonalInfo().get(i).getEmployeeID()%>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View Profile</a>
                                            <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>







                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, what happens is this: 
[image]

This is the following solution I tried:
Trying to create 3 layouts and incrementing the value in the for loop. (3 divs, i, i+1, i+2 in the for loop). However, I can't access my modal in this way because of messed up applicantids. Any tips?

EDIT: In the first place, can I achieve the layout I wanted by using only 1 loop?

Comment: To see what is your problem, you should try to create it yourself first. Then see the layout you need to rebuild with your loop. I only see one loop so this is probably your problem to create the correct column (but I am not a big fan of bootstrap so not sure)

Comment: I tried to create this layout first but what happens is the same with the picture I uploaded.

Comment: So this is not a JSP issues with your loop. This is strictly a bootstrap question ;) Once you will be able to create this layout in pure HTML, it will be much easier to recreate it in JSP.

Answer (score -1):

Try seeing the css that is causing the div to be a new row instead of aligning in one line. You can use inspect element for that in browser

Comment: But I can't use PHP sir. I can only use Java because this is written in my document. I have the closing bracket that you are saying I just didnt include it because I still have code under the snippet and it is very long. Thi s is the only relevant part of my code

Comment: There are no issues when it comes to loop. I can get the values no problem. My only problem is how to present the data that I have (Check the pictures I posted.)

Comment: oh sorry for misunderstanding. now I got your question.. the first class change it to md-4 I think that should fix it

Comment: unfortunately sir the layout just got smaller but it didnt went the way i want it to be

Comment: do you have the live version of the current website... if so please give me the link so I can examine code from my browser using inspect element

Comment: I dont have a live website because I am only using localhost, but this is my file: http://paste.ofcode.org/gBPdhWWrc5jfE4g642LLbR

I used hardcoded files instead of getting it from the DB so you can access it

Comment: can you try again? I enabled my remote connection so maybe thats the error. 

194 775 305
x671be

Comment: Why?? I dont what what I did but I enabled every remote connection related stuff I know. Please try again.

https://postimg.org/image/4vjvni519/
Here is the pic of my teamviewer.

194 775 305
un5s47

Comment: last try vd7b63 is the pass same id

Comment: Forget the above one, Download this pretty quick -https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en and let me know... And I am leaving will be back in 2-3 hours

Comment: You are suggesting to change all is project into PHP ? Nice ;) And you should not send remote access here ... you are not alone !

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311869/should-we-allow-people-to-offer-help-via-outside-communications-like-teamviewer/311917#311917

Comment: @AxelH I initially thought it a different that what was asked. Then I quickly got what the actual concern was and then suggested accordingly. But without seeing all the css in action it is not possible to tell the exact cause why the row is getting broken. Yes you maybe right in not sharing teamviewer credentials publically but not every stranger is a bad guy. I just wanted to help as he didnt have a live version of the site

Comment: Simply ask more information about his question, you can even ask a [mcve] to reproduce his problem. ` not every stranger is a bad guy`, but to protect a kid, you told them to trust nobody ;)

Comment: Yes you are right on that part :) Can I ask for providing a zip of his whole working folder so we can help out by taking codes in our hands?

Comment: A [mcve] is better to have every information on SO. A file sharing system will not keep the archive long so a futur visitor might not find enought information to see if it is the same problem as this one.

Comment: So what should I do now? I can provide zip of the project. It is just a school project using bootstrap

Comment: Yes provide me the complete zip of the project.. make sure it contains all the files and post and link to the zip file here..

Comment: I will add a explanation update in my answer to what I did if I fix the issue